# Reading JSON file using a SQL Server 2016 query - child records issue

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have the following JSON file named (**C:\temp\test.json**) that has a main record and three child records structured like this:

```
 [{ 
  "dc:type":{ 
     "dc:title":"AMC",
     "dc:type":"recordType",
     "rdf:resource":"https://tmkl.at1/16777434"
  },
  "dc:title":"CCP00113620",
  "RM_Approved_on":"2011-12-19T13:04:36Z",
  "Title":"RAM PROGRAM PLAN",
  "Project":{ 
     "oslc_cm:label":"HTLS",
     "rdf:resource":"https://tmkl.at1/16789988-34271859"
  },
  "Drawing":"N",
  "Attachments":{ 
     "oslc_cm:results":[ 
        { 
           "rdf:about":"https://tmkl.at1/16777434-33668052/field/Attachments/attachment/16782994-34738717",
           "dc:type":{ 
              "dc:title":"AMC",
              "dc:type":"recordType",
              "rdf:resource":"https://tmkl.at1./16777434"
           },
           "dc:title":"Doc-review-sheet-CCP00113620.xls",
           "filename":"Doc-1234-CCP00113620.xls"
        },
        { 
           "rdf:about":"https://tmkl.at1/16777434-33668052/field/Attachments/attachment/16782994-34736984",
           "dc:type":{ 
              "dc:title":"AMC",
              "dc:type":"recordType",
              "rdf:resource":"https://tmkl.at1./16777434"
           },
           "dc:title":"Doc-review-sheet-CCP00113620-JD.xls",
           "filename":"Doc-CCP00113620-JD300.xls"
        },
        { 
           "rdf:about":"https://tmkl.at1/16777434-33668052/field/Attachments/attachment/16782994-34738722",
           "dc:type":{ 
              "dc:title":"AMC",
              "dc:type":"recordType",
              "rdf:resource":"https://tmkl.at1./16777434"
           },
           "dc:title":"3CU 05007 0009 UMZZA-Rev01-B_edited.doc",
           "filename":"UMZZA-Rev01-B_edited.doc"
        }
     ],
     "oslc_cm:collref":"https://tmkl.at1/16777434-33668052/field/Attachments"
  },
  "rdf:about":"https://tmkl.at1/16777434-33668052"
 },
 { 
    "dc:type":{ 
       "dc:title":"AMC",
       "dc:type":"recordType",
       "rdf:resource":"https://tmkl.at1./16777434"
    }]
```

I would like to read this file (**C:\temp\test.json**) using a sql SQL Server 2016 query and obtain the following result:

```
id                Project      Title             Filename        Web-address  
CCP00113620         HTLS       RAM PROGRAM PLAN   Doc-1234-CCP00113620.xls https://tmkl.at1/16777434-33668052/field/Attachments/attachment/16782994-34738717
CCP00113620         HTLS       RAM PROGRAM PLAN   Doc-CCP00113620-JD300.xls https://tmkl.at1/16777434-33668052/field/Attachments/attachment/16782994-34736984
CCP00113620         HTLS       RAM PROGRAM PLAN   UMZZA-Rev01-B_edited.doc  https://tmkl.at1/16777434-33668052/field/Attachments/attachment/16782994-34738722
```

I tried the following query :

```
SELECT ecn_att.*,q1.* 
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'd:\temp\ecn_att.json', SINGLE_CLOB) as j 
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(BulkColumn) 
WITH( 
      [id] [varchar](16), 
      [Project] [varchar](200), 
      [Title] [varchar](200), 
      [Attachments] nvarchar(max) AS JSON   
 ) AS ecn_att 
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON ([Attachments]) 
WITH (
      [dc:type] [varchar](max)
) as Q1
```

I am unable to get the child records

Comment: What is the question? Have you tried something that didn't work or are you asking for a link to the [JSON functions, especially JSON_QUERY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/validate-query-and-change-json-data-with-built-in-functions-sql-server)?

Comment: Or are you asking about some ETL process that reads the JSON file, processes it and inserts the results into a table? There are several duplicate questions. SQL Server's ETL service is SSIS which *doesn't* have a JSON source. There are third party components though. Or you could load the file into a single row and use JSON_QUERY to parse it and insert the data into the target. A faster idea would be to write a small C# program that reads the file with eg Json.NET, deserializes the entries into objects and inserts them to the database with SqlBulkCopy

Comment: I just need an SQL Query that reads the JSON file. I tried something like this: SELECT ecn_att.*,q1.*  FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'd:\temp\ecn_att.json', SINGLE_CLOB) as j
   CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(BulkColumn)
   WITH(
   [id] [varchar](16),
   [Project] [varchar](200),
   [Title] [varchar](200),
   [Attachments] nvarchar(max) AS JSON 
   ) AS ecn_att
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON ([Attachments]) WITH ([dc:type] [varchar](max)) as Q1 I am unable to get the child records

Comment: Queries read tables, not files. You are asking how to *import* a json file, parse the contents and insert them into a table. That's not "just"

Comment: Please read carefully the question, actually SQL Server 2016 CAN READ a JSON file and return a recordset

Comment: Check the [Parse JSON documents into rows and columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/import-json-documents-into-sql-server#parse-json-documents-into-rows-and-columns) section in the docs. It shows how to open a file and read records assuming the format is simple (ie no deep nesting)

Comment: Also read [Convert JSON Data to Rows and Columns with OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/convert-json-data-to-rows-and-columns-with-openjson-sql-server). It shows how to handle more complex cases.

Comment: Update the question and post what you tried, what went wrong. Post your query in the question, not the comments.

Comment: Thanks Kanavos for looking into this, I found the answer, I am posting the result. The problem was I had to enclose the name of the JSON child element in double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This the correct query that returns the expected result. The tricky part was to enclose the name of the child element [oslc_cm:results] in double quotes:

```
 SELECT ecn_att.*,q1.*  FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'd:\temp\ecn_att.json', SINGLE_CLOB) as j
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(BulkColumn)
     WITH(
        [id] [varchar](16),
        [Project] [varchar](200),
        [Title] [varchar](200),
        [Attachments] nvarchar(max) AS JSON 
        ) AS ecn_att
         CROSS APPLY OPENJSON ([Attachments],'$."oslc_cm:results"') WITH ([filename] nvarchar(max), [rdf:about] nvarchar(max)) as Q1
```